# Positioning the bottom action bar in Android [ActionBarSherlock]

Tags: admob, actionbarsherlock

Ok, So I am implementing [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) in one of my applications and I have an Activity that has a split action bar (as shown below).

[image]

Now the thing is that I need the bottom bar to displayed above and not below the ad.

The layout of my page looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/Fill" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL_app"
    style="@style/Fill.RL"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/XXX"
        style="@style/FillWrap.List" />

    <include layout="@layout/network_error" />

    <include layout="@layout/error_no_live" />
</LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/ad_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. The action bar exists outside of the content view available to your application. You are only able to place things below the top bar and above the split action bar (if present).

If you really need this, your best bet would be to create your own version of the split action bar in your layout with a `LinearLayout` and set of `Button`s which use the normal themes the action bar would be using.